# How to convert token to Authentication in spring security?

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I use keycloak as Idp. And I use a keycloak client to get jwt token from keycloak.

when I use the token to call the api in my springboot app which secred by `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` and `spring-security`. I find KeycloakAuthenticationFilter can get `Authentication` from `SecurityContext`.

why? Where is convert token to Authentication and put it in `SecurityContext`?

Answer (score 0):

when use keycloak token call rest api, KeycloakAuthenticationFilter will go to auth.

1. use token to authenticate by authenticator
   [image: token auth]
2. in authenticator, will verify token, if success, will put it to SecurityContext.

[image: token complete]

3. but how to put to SecurityContext has some variant

[image: implment]

you can clike one to see how to finish this step.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).